# QTableView column width

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm struggling to set column width manually in a `QTableView`.
Why doesn't this piece of code work?

```
tabb = new QTableView;
tabb->resizeColumnsToContents();

for (int col=0; col<20; col++) 
{
   tabb->setColumnWidth(col,80);
}
```

If I omit `tabb->resizeColumnsToContents();` it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should set model first and after this you will be able to change `ColumnWidth`:

```
tabb = new QTableView;
tabb->setModel(someModel);

for (int col=0; col<20; col++) 
{
   tabb->setColumnWidth(col,80);
}
```

Comment: I used your post in this way: tabb->setColumnWidth(col, tabb->width());

Comment: If you have customized header, you should use setColumnWidth() after setHorizontalHeader().