# Store list values in QTableWidget in pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtabwidget

Code:

```
myresult = [(449, u'text1', u'checkbox'), (454, u'text2', u'textbox'), (455, u'text3', u'textbox')]
row = 0
for x, x1, x2 in myresult:
g = int(''.join(map(str, x)))  # int type
l = ''.join(x1)  # string type
k = ''.join(x2)  # string type
rcount_general = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
self.tableWidget.insertRow(rcount_general)
r = 0
for i in range(rcount_general + 1):
     if (k == "textbox"):
                self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox()

                lis = ("---select---", "description", "multiple_input")

                self.cb.addItems(lis)
                self.cb.setCurrentIndex(1)
                self.tableWidget_2.setCellWidget(rcount_general, 2, self.cb)
            elif (k == "checkbox"):
                self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox()

                lis = ("---select---", "description", "multiple_input")

                self.cb.addItems(lis)
                self.cb.setCurrentIndex(2)
                self.tableWidget_2.setCellWidget(rcount_general, 2, self.cb)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(g))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(l))

    r = r + 1
row = row + 1
```

Error:

g = ''.join(map(str, x))
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

please check below attached image which has expected output  .Thank you in advance

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to use join, here it is only necessary to use enumerate:

```
myresult = [(449, u'text1', u'checkbox'), (454, u'text2', u'textbox'), (455, u'text3', u'textbox')]

for row, result in enumerate(myresult):
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
    for column, value in enumerate(result):
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
        if column == 2:
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems([value, "---select---", "description", "multiple_input"])
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, combo)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Comment: How to set particular tablewidget column width in pyqt4

Comment: @sandeeppawar read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681578/qtableview-column-width, `self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(col, width)`

Comment: Its not working for QTableWidget because  setColumnWidth(col,width) is an attribute of QTableView().Any other way for set colum width of QTableWidget()

Comment: @sandeeppawar QTableWidget inherits from QTableView so this method should work